# In my Airbnb clone developed with Next.js, I am unable to add a Listing to favorites

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

My Airbnb clone project developed with Next.js, I am unable to add a Listing to favorites.
The heart button(component) color is not changing when clicked, even though I receive a success response.
The addition to favorites is not being saved in the database.(I am using MongoDB and prisma)
The hasFavorited variable always returns false because it is trying to find the listingId within an empty array.

This is my ListingCard.tsx: (app/components/listings/ListingCard.tsx)

```
'use client';

import { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import useCountries from "@/app/hooks/useCountries";
import { SafeUser } from "@/app/types";
import { Listing, Reservation } from "@prisma/client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import Image from "next/image";
import HeartButton from "../HeartButton";
import Button from "../Button";

interface ListingCardProps {
    data: Listing;
    reservation?: Reservation;
    onAction?: (id: string) => void;
    disabled?: boolean;
    actionLabel?: string;
    actionId?: string;
    currentUser?: SafeUser | null;

}

const ListingCard:React.FC<ListingCardProps> = ({
    data,
    reservation,
    onAction,
    disabled,
    actionId = "",
    actionLabel,
    currentUser 
}) => {

    const router = useRouter();
    const { getByValue } = useCountries();
    const location = getByValue(data.locationValue);

    const handleCancel = useCallback(
      (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (disabled) {
            return;
        }
        onAction?.(actionId);
      },
      [actionId, onAction, disabled]
    );

    const price = useMemo(() => {
        if (reservation) {
            return reservation.totalPrice;
        }
        return data.price;
    }, [reservation, data.price]);

    const reservationDate = useMemo(() => {
        if (!reservation) {
            return null;
        }
        const start = new Date(reservation.startDate);
        const end = new Date(reservation.endDate);
        return `${format(start,'PP')} - ${format(end,'PP')}`;

    }, [reservation]);
    
  return (
    <div
    onClick={()=>router.push(`/listings/${data.id}`)}
     className="col-span-1 cursor-pointer group">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 w-full">
            <div className="aspect-square w-full relative overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
                <Image 
                 alt="Listing"
                 src={data.imageSrc}
                 fill
                 className="object-cover h-full w-full group-hover:scale-110 transition"
                />
                <div className="absolute top-3 right-3">
                    <HeartButton
                        listingId={data.id}
                        currentUser = {currentUser}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="font-semibold text-lg">
                {location?.region}, {location?.label}
            </div>
            <div className="font-light text-neutral-500">
                {reservationDate || data.category}
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row items-center gap-1">
                <div className="font-semibold">
                    $ {price}
                </div>
                {!reservation && (
                    <div className="font-light">night</div>
                )}
            </div>
            {onAction && actionLabel && (
                <Button 
                    disabled={disabled}
                    small
                    label={actionLabel}
                    onClick={handleCancel}
                />
            )}

        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default ListingCard
```

This is my useFavorite.ts hooks: (app/hooks/useFavorite.ts)

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";
import { SafeUser } from "../types";
 
import useLoginModal from "./useLoginModal";

interface IUseFavorite {
    listingId: string;
    currentUser?: SafeUser | null;
}


const useFavorite = ({ listingId, currentUser }: IUseFavorite) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const loginModal = useLoginModal();
    
    
    const hasFavorited = useMemo(() => {
        // console.log(currentUser?.favoriteIds);
        // console.log(listingId);
        const list = currentUser?.favoriteIds || [];
        // list.push(listingId);
        return list.includes(listingId);

    }, [currentUser, listingId]);


    const toggleFavorite = useCallback(async (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        e.stopPropagation();

        if(!currentUser) {
            // login modal will open if tries to add to favorites without logging in.
            return loginModal.onOpen();
        }
        // console.log(currentUser);

        try {
            let request;

            if (hasFavorited) {
                request = () => axios.delete(`/api/favorites/${listingId}`);
            } else {
                request = () => axios.post(`/api/favorites/${listingId}`);
            }
            await request();
            router.refresh();
            toast.success('Success');

        } catch (error) {
            toast.error('Something went wrong');
        }

    }, [currentUser, hasFavorited, listingId, loginModal, router]);
    // console.log(hasFavorited);

    return {
        hasFavorited,
        toggleFavorite
    }

}

export default useFavorite;
```

This is my route.ts (app/api/favorites/[listingId]/route.ts) :

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import getCurrentUser from "@/app/actions/getCurrentUser";
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";


interface IParams {
    listingId?: string;
}

export async function POST(request: Request, { params }: { params:IParams } ) {

    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
    if (!currentUser) {
        return NextResponse.error();
    }
    
    const { listingId } = params;
    // console.log("route listing id: " + listingId);
    if (!listingId || typeof listingId !== 'string') {
        throw new Error('Invalid ID');
    }

    let favoriteIds = [...(currentUser.favoriteIds || [])];

    favoriteIds.push(listingId);

    const user = prisma.user.update({
        where: {
            id: currentUser.id
        },
        data: {
            favoriteIds: favoriteIds
        }
    });
    
    return NextResponse.json(user);

}

export async function DELETE(request:Request, { params }: { params: IParams }) {
    const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

    if (!currentUser) {
        return NextResponse.error();
    }

    const { listingId } = params;

    if (!listingId || typeof listingId !== 'string') {
        throw new Error('Invalid ID');
    }

    let favoriteIds = [...(currentUser.favoriteIds || [])];

    favoriteIds = favoriteIds.filter((id) => id !== listingId);
    // the selected id out of array
    const user = await prisma.user.update({
        where: {
            id: currentUser.id
        },
        data: {
            favoriteIds: favoriteIds
        }
    });

    return NextResponse.json(user);

}
```

This is my HeartButton.tsx component (app/components/HeartButton.tsx):

```
'use client';

import { AiFillHeart, AiOutlineHeart } from "react-icons/ai";
import { SafeUser } from "../types";
import useFavorite from "../hooks/useFavorite";
import ClientOnly from "./ClientOnly";

interface HeartButtonProps {
    listingId: string;
    currentUser?: SafeUser | null
}

const HeartButton: React.FC<HeartButtonProps> = ({
    listingId,
    currentUser
}) => {

    // we are gonna modified later.
    // const hasFavorited = false;
    // const toggleFavorite = () => {};
    
    // replaced it with useFavorite hook
    // console.log(listingId);
    const { hasFavorited, toggleFavorite } = useFavorite({listingId, currentUser});
    // console.log(hasFavorited);

  return (
    <div onClick={toggleFavorite}
    className="relative hover:opacity-80 transition cursor-pointer">
        <AiOutlineHeart
            size={28}
            className="fill-white absolute -top-[2px] -right-[2px]" 
        />
        <AiFillHeart 
            size={24}
            className={
                hasFavorited ? "fill-rose-600" : "fill-neutral-500/70"
            }
        />
    </div>
  )
}

export default HeartButton
```

I understand that it might be a simple error,(useFavorited always return false) but I couldn't solve it. I have tried various solutions, but they didn't work. I'm still new to this, so please understand.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, change everything from "favoriteIds" to "favorites". This works for me.

useFavorite.ts hooks: (app/hooks/useFavorite.ts)

```
const hasFavorited = useMemo(() => {
    const list = currentUser?.favorites || [];
    // list. Push(listingId);
    return list. Includes(listingId);

}, [currentUser, listingId]);
```

route.ts (app/api/favorites/[listingId]/route.ts) :

```js
export async function POST(request: Request, { params }: { params: IParams }) {
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
  if (!currentUser) {
    return NextResponse.error();
  }

  const { listingId } = params;
  // console.log("route listing id: " + listingId);
  if (!listingId || typeof listingId !== "string") {
    throw new Error("Invalid ID");
  }

  let favorites = [...(currentUser.favorites || [])];

  favorites.push(listingId);

  const user = prisma.user.update({
    where: {
      id: currentUser.id,
    },
    data: {
      favorites,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(user);
}
```

Do the same for the DELETE function